# Problem with latex format string in python plot with double subscripts and expectation symbol

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am having some trouble producing the following axis label in `matplotlib`, using the standard `format` notation with strings.

[image]

However, I am getting all sorts of errors when I try to do this with the standard `format` usage on strings. E.g. this one relates to the x-label:

> ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string

I would like to do this using `plt.xlabel(r"$m_{{}_{}}$".format('A',0))` but cannot get it to work at present. The same goes for the y-label where the expectation symbol is causing problems by the looks of it.

A (broken) MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{amssymb}')
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.rc('font', size=20)

plt.plot(np.random.rand(100),'b')
plt.xlabel(r"$m_{{}_{}}$".format('A',0))
plt.ylabel(r"$\mathbb{E}[{} \mid {}_{}]$".format('B','A',0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{amssymb}')
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.rc('font', size=20)
 
plt.plot(np.random.rand(100),'b')
plt.xlabel(r"$m_{{{}_{}}}$".format('A',0))
plt.ylabel(r"$\mathbb{{E}}[{} \mid {}_{}]$".format('B','A',0))

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Plot with labels in latex format]